# Problem with runing "ps" command on my own linux shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, posix

I'm building for a while my own linux shell as part of my academy project. I have reached to a problem when i'm trying to run "ps" command after the command line "/usr/bin/wc text_file.txt". When I'm trying so - the following error message is shown:

```
0: /usr/bin/wc shell.c
  751  3273 24140 shell.c
1: ps
error: garbage option

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

The followig code is responsible on running the commands in my shell without path (aka "ps"):

```
void cmd_commands_without_path(char** parsed,unused struct tokens *tokens) 
{
    pid_t pid = fork(); // Forking a child 
    char* s = getenv("PATH"); // Holds the full environment var path.
    int i = 0; // Counter.
    int symbol_counting = 0; // Holds the number of ":" in the full environment path.
    char *temp; // Helps with the initielizing of the new path.
    char *symbol = "/"; // Holds "/" for correcting the new path.


    /* Puts the user command into an array with NULL in the end. */
    while((tokens_get_token(tokens,i)) != NULL) // While we did not reached to the end of user input.
    {
        parsed[i] = tokens_get_token(tokens,i); // Initielize parsed to hold the user input (command).
        i++;
    }
    parsed[i+1] = NULL; // The end of the user input (command) will be NULL (for execv).

    /* Count the number of ":" in the path. */
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == ':')
        {
            symbol_counting++; // increasing symbol counting.
        }
    }
    symbol_counting++; // Because have to be an address after the last ":"
    
    if (pid == -1) // If the creation of the child was unsuccessful.
    { 
        printf("\nFailed forking child.."); 
        return; 
    } 
    else if (pid == 0) // The child was returned.
    { 
     setpgrp(); // Changing the child group id.
     tcsetpgrp(0,getpgrp()); // Return the proccess id of the child.
     
     /* Signals for "ctrl" options. */
     signal(SIGINT,SIG_DFL);
     signal(SIGQUIT,SIG_DFL);
     signal(SIGKILL,SIG_DFL);
     signal(SIGTERM,SIG_DFL);
     signal(SIGTSTP,SIG_DFL);
     signal(SIGCONT,SIG_DFL);
     signal(SIGTTIN,SIG_DFL);
     signal(SIGTTOU,SIG_DFL);
     
        char* full_array[(symbol_counting+1)]; // Create new array at the size of the number of ":".
        i = 0; // Restarting the counter.
        
        /* Initielize array with the seperate environment variable paths. */
        full_array[i] = strtok(s, ":");
        for(i = 1; i < symbol_counting; i++)
        {
            full_array[i] = strtok(NULL, ":");
        }
        
        for(i = 0; i < symbol_counting; i++) // Runs as the number of phats.
        {
            temp = (char*)malloc(MAXLIST*sizeof(char)); // Allocate to temp size of 1024 chars.
            temp[0] = '\0'; // Erasing temp.
        
        if(temp[0] == '\0') // If the word was ended.
        {
            strcpy(temp,full_array[i]); // Adds to temp the path we currently gonna check.
            temp = strcat(temp, symbol); // Adds "/" to the new path.
            temp = strcat(temp, parsed[0]); // Adds to the new path the user command.
            
        
            if(access(temp, X_OK) == 0) // If the command was found in the path.
            {
                execv(temp,parsed); // Executing the command.
            }
            temp[0] = '\0'; // Erasing temp again.
        }
        }
        return; 
    } 
    else // pid > 0
    { 
        // waiting for child to terminate 
        wait(NULL);
        tcsetpgrp(0,getpgrp()); // Return the proccess id of the child.
        return; 
    } 
}
```

I should also say that this error occures only when im trying to run the "ps" command after the command "/usr/bin/wc text.txt".
Can anyone give me a clue what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'd print out the array of arguments to ps to see what you're sending. That will probably tell you something. I suspect you've got data you aren't cleaning up in between calls to this method.

Comment: I have tried to clean up the memory but nothing changes..

Comment: Did you try printing out the arguments array immediately before the exec?